# Is Infinispan.xml mandatory?

Tags: infinispan

May be a silly question..
To create a stand alone cache,
Is "infinispan.xml" mandatory OR can be avoided through programmatic configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/x/bYNa - you can create a cache from XML and from programmatic configuration.